# why does letter s pronounced differently in word resume and assume?

Tags: word-difference, pronunciation

In `assume` `consume`,`s` is pronounced as /s/,but in `resume` `presume`,s is pronounced as /z/.why?

The 4 words have a common root `sume` which is from Latin,but get different pronunciation eventually.

Comment: Please do not expect English spelling to make any sense at all. Its [crazines is legendary](http://www.etni.org.il/farside/funpoem.htm).

Comment: *assume* and *consume* are derived from Latin words, while *resume* and *presume* are derived from French words. Check a dictionary. While English has so many phonetic variations, the language a word derives from has a lot to do with the pronunciation.

Comment: See [When to pronounce ‹s› as /z/ in the middle of words?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30195) It isn't about whether the word is from Latin or French, and it isn't totally random either. It's fairly predictable that "consume" is pronounced with /s/, because "ns" in the middle of a word is usually /ns/; the other words are a bit less predictable, but follow the tendency for single intervocalic "s" after a prefix and before a stressed vowel to represent /z/ while double "ss" represents /s/.