# Are there words with the letter C in which its pronounced like Z?

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

Are there words in English with the letter **C** in which it's really pronounced as **Z**?

By googling I found [an old book](https://books.google.com/books?id=pkZAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR18&lpg=PR18&dq=c%20which%20%22sounds%20like%20z%22&source=bl&ots=4mEzh_5Vcl&sig=WM95JqO6ZBbQc3qTa2hqFngox-c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr25nX-8XXAhXLFJoKHRYMAi84ChDoAQgyMAM#v=onepage&q&f=false) which counts these words as in which letter C sounds like Z: ***suffice, discern, sacrifice***. But checking it in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sacrifice) raises that it is not true or not updated and those words pronounce as C rather than Z.

Another old book ([The Oxford Spelling Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=s05gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=c%20which%20%22sounds%20like%20z%22&source=bl&ots=qxo58S87XV&sig=tq5OezSBA3vJij4yXxtFVse8sN8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr25nX-8XXAhXLFJoKHRYMAi84ChDoAQg9MAU#v=onepage&q=c%20which%20%22sounds%20like%20z%22&f=false)) says:

> "C sounds like Z in [squinancy](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=thAPWu6_H4qvkwXj7pCQCw&q=SQUINANCY&oq=SQUINANCY&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i67k1j0i30k1l3j0i10i30k1.96784.96784.0.98135.1.1.0.0.0.0.409.409.4-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.409....0.Rq_Wt36ASvk) which is pronounced like quinzy"

[image]

Comment: The final syllable of *suffice* and *sacrifice* rhymes with "rice", not with "rise".

Comment: Cambridge dictionary transcripts sacrifice as /ˈsæk.rɪ.faɪs. See here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sacrifice

Comment: Yes, and it has this for **rice**:  `/raɪs/`    Contrast **prize**: `/praɪz/`

Comment: That means that none of them has letter C which is pronounced as Z.

Comment: I agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo - The final _c_ in _suffice_ and _sacrifice_ sound more like _s_ than _z_.

Comment: It might have been true in 1810 but not now.

Comment: In *discern* the sound may be *s* or *z* or something in between. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discern) shows both pronunciations.

Comment: The name of the city of Quincy (in Massachusetts) is pronounced with a z, like "quinzy".

Comment: It is actually possible to hea `/faɪz/` with the verb "sacrifice"  now and then from native speakers in the Philadelphia Pennsylvania area, near where I live, and Websters dictionary from 1864 has `/faɪz/` .   But the overwhelming majority of speakers of AmE nowadays would say /faɪs/

Answer (score 3):

The only examples I can find after searching are proper nouns: The city of Quincy (/ˈkwɪnzi/ KWIN-zee) as mentioned in comments, and the highest mountain in Australia Mount Kosciuszko (/ˌkɒziˈʌskoʊ/).

Standard (i.e. RP or GA) pronunciations of sacrifice and discern now use /s/.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to occur in one pronunciation of the rare (or even archaic) word *sice,* defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sice) as

> the number six on a die : a throw of six in dice

MW gives the pronunciation as \ˈsīs, ˈsīz\; the Oxford English Dictionary agrees that it can be pronounced with /z/ in American English (although the OED only lists the pronunciation with final /s/ for British English).

I have never heard this word; I just came across it in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

No, in English, C either makes a [k] or [s] sound so c in "suffice", "sacrifice" and "discern" are all [s]. The c making a [z] in "suffice" is obsolete pronounciation. S makes a [z] sound in words like "phrase".

Comment: Hello Akshat,  this question is from 2017 and so six years old.  I'm not sure your new answer adds much to the answers that are already here. You can be more useful to the community by answering new questions or adding a different insight to older ones.